# How to connect input and output on Bistable Multivibrator

Tags: breadboard, output, input, multivibrator

I built the circuit below on my breadboard. I've checked every connection and it doesn't work. The thing I didn't know how to do was connecting the output (a LED) and the input. (a button) I did something pretty random and, no surprise, it doesn't work. My question is how do I connect the input and output and can I do it with a button and a LED?

[image]

I will use this as a SR Flip-Flop, I found it can be used this way [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html).

Also, I've used 3.3k resistors instead of 3.9k resistors. Is that bad?

Comment: Try simulating your circuit first to understand the values you are getting. What is obvious to me is that the output won't be able to drive an LED high, only pull it low.

Comment: What do you have available for a trigger input? You can put an LED in series with 2K in parallel with one of the 3K9 resistors.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Why 2K?

Comment: Since the drawing shows a low-going pulse for the trigger input, connect a resistor from the trigger input to +Vcc, and your switch from the trigger input to ground.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why not?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany What Vcc are you assuming? It should be able to drive enough current for the LED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The LEDs should go in the collector circuits for each transistor, as shown above.  The 3.9K resistors should be reduced (470 Ω shown here) to provide sufficient drive for the LEDs.

Other than that, I would leave the rest of your circuit as is.

This circuit also has separate switches for the set and reset functions.

Other ways of triggering are as follows:

[image]

The circuit on the left uses a pushbutton, and connects up to the Trigger input of your original schematic.

The one on the right uses a SPDT switch; you could also use a On-Off-On center off switch.

Comment: The LED works great but I can't toggle it on or off. Also, could my circuit use a button to do both set and reset? Where and how would I connect it? (in my circuit)

Comment: @Atom I have updated my answer with a couple of suggestions.

Comment: What resistor and capacitor should I use for the pushbutton circuit? Also can I use 6 volts instead of 5?

Comment: @Atom Try 20K and 0.1 µF.  If that doesn't debounce the switch adequately (flip-flop toggles more than once per button switch), increase the resistor value.  The positive rail should be connected to the same voltage as Vcc in your original schematic.

Comment: Nah, the pushbutton circuit doesn't work for me, I guess something's wrong in my circuit. Anyone have a suggestion?